# Nested CSS classes in li/ul

Tags: html, css, web, html-lists

I have a nested li and they have specific classes. I am having issues with the nested classes. Despite the specific class, the styling is that of the class of the parent:

```
<ul>    
<li class="navtitle-current"><a href="1.html">ONE</a>
    <ul>
    <li class="navtitle-current"><a href="2.html">TWO</a></li>
    <li class="navtitle"><a href="3.html">THREE</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

.navtitle {
    font-weight: none;
}

.navtitle a{
    background-color:white;
    color: gray;
}

.navtitle a:hover,
.navtitle:hover{
    background-color:white;
    color: black;
}

.navtitle-current {
    font-weight: none;
}

.navtitle-current a{
    background-color:white;
    color: black;
}

.navtitle-current a:hover,
.navtitle-current:hover{
    background-color:white;
    color: black;
}
```

What I want to happen is that ONE needs to be in black, TWO in black and THREE in gray. However, all the links are black.

I was under the impression that if I explicitly have a class, I should not have any such issues. Does anyone have any thoughts?

All help is appreciated.

Note: I realize the CSS blocks are not in . I just put the code on here for the sake of showing what I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet another way to go about this:

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/kHcpY/)**

```
.navtitle-current .navtitle  a  {
    background-color:white;
    color: gray; 
}
```

It may be just a personal preference, but when possible I try to avoid chaining ul li ul li etc. I find it a bit more readable to use the class names.

Answer (score 2):

Because `.navtitle-current` is higher level than `.navtitle`, the links are inheriting the `.navtitle-current a` styles. If you want to style links inside that, you need to be more specific with your tags. Change `.navtitle a` to `.navtitle-current .navtitle a` and it should work.

Comment: Eh, as long as someone did =)

Comment: I wish I could accept both your answers, but alas. Thank you though.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is selector specificity - your second to last declaration has [the same exact same weight and origin](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) as the class defining the gray-colored text - `.navtitle a` - and due to the nature of the cascade, the latter rule specified will win

From the [2.1 Spec, Specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity):

> Finally, sort by order specified: if two declarations have the same weight, origin and specificity, the latter specified wins. Declarations in imported style sheets are considered to be before any declarations in the style sheet itself.

To overcome this, just increase the specificity of `.navtitle  a` by including `li` before the class, e.g.

```
 li.navtitle a {
 background-color: gray;
 color: gray;
 }
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/TQwf7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it more clever:

```
<div class="titles">
  <ul>  
    <li class="current"><a href="1.html">ONE</a>
      <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="2.html">TWO</a></li>
        <li><a href="3.html">THREE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

.titles ul li {...}
.titles ul li.current {...}
.titles ul li.current ul li {...}
.titles ul li.current ul li.current {...}
```

regards,